# Square of uniformly convergent functions is not always uniformly convergent

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

For each $n ∈ N$ and $x ∈ R$ let
$f_n(x) = x + \frac{1}{n}$,
and for each $x ∈ R$ let
$f(x) = x$.
Working directly from the deﬁnition of uniform convergence (i.e. without using the Uniform Norm Theo-rem), show that

(i) $f_n$ converges uniformly to f, but

(ii) $f^2_n$ does not converge uniformly to $f^2$.

Obviously the hypothesis is true but I'm having trouble showing this rigorously as required by the problem.
This is what I have so far.

$f_n→f$ uniformly in $A$ if for any $ϵ>0$ there exists $N(ϵ)$ such that $n≥N(ϵ)⟹|f_n(x)−f(x)|<ϵ,∀x∈A$

So we can fix $\epsilon>0$ and then there exists $N(ϵ)$ such that $n≥N(ϵ)⟹|x + \frac{1}{n} - x|<ϵ,∀x∈A$. Then we have that $n≥N(ϵ)⟹|\frac{1}{n}|<ϵ,∀x∈A$. As $n \to \infty  \frac {1}{n} \to 0$. Then we have that $\epsilon >0$ which we fixed earlier.

Now I need to show that there exists some $\epsilon$ for which $n≥N(ϵ)⟹|f_n^2(x) -f^2(x)|\geϵ,∀x∈A$. From this we get that $n≥N(ϵ)⟹|x^2 + \frac{2x}{n} + \frac{1}{n^2} -x^2|\geϵ,∀x∈A$ is what I have to show. Simplified I have to show that $n≥N(ϵ)⟹|\frac {1}{n}(x + \frac{1}{n})|\geϵ,∀x∈A$

This is where I have trouble. I thought that If I choose $\epsilon = \frac{\epsilon}{n}$ this would work but then I would have to show that  $n≥N(ϵ)⟹|x+\frac{1}{n}| \ge \epsilon$.

I'm very confused as how to show that this is true rigorously. Thank You in advance.

Comment: You got your negation wrong. You need to show that for every $N$ there exists some $n \geqslant N$ and some $x\in A$ with $\lvert f_n^2(x) - f^2(x)\rvert \geqslant \epsilon$.

Comment: Ok I understand but where do I go from there? I still have to find an $n$ such that $n≥N(ϵ)⟹|\frac {1}{n}(x + \frac{1}{n})|\geϵ,∀x∈A$

Comment: In fact, assuming $A = \mathbb{R}$ ($A\subset\mathbb{R}$ unbounded suffices, and if $A$ is bounded, $f(x) = x$ doesn't work anyway), you can, given an arbitrary $\epsilon > 0$, for every $n$ find an $x_n$ such that $\lvert f_n^2(x_n) - f^2(x_n)\rvert > \epsilon$.

Comment: How would I find such an $x_n$ though if $\epsilon >0$ is arbitrary?

Comment: $\lvert f_n^2(x) - f^2(x)\rvert = \left\lvert \frac{2x}{n} + \frac{1}{n^2}\right\rvert \geqslant \frac{2\lvert x\rvert}{n} - \frac{1}{n^2}$. Take a sharp look.

Comment: But any sequence of $x_n \in R$ would demonstrate what you just said to be true. So could I let $\epsilon = \frac{2|x|}{n} - \frac{1}{n^2}?$

Comment: $\epsilon$ is fixed. Take $\epsilon = 1$ for simplicity or concreteness. You need to find an appropriate $x_n$ for every $n$.

Comment: What if I choose $x_n =n$ when $\epsilon = 1$ is fixed? In that way I have $|2+\frac {1}{n^2}| > \epsilon$ for every $n$.

Comment: That's something easy that works. (Provided the domain is $\mathbb{R}$, otherwise take an $x_n\in A$ such that $\lvert x_n\rvert \geqslant n$.)

Comment: Ok I see, what you just said is more generalized. Thank You very much for your help.